# How to replicate bios_grub partition?

Tags: partition, disk, aws, parted

I have a 60GB AWS volume which I want to shrink to 30GB. The plan is to manually recreate the same partition table (with the only difference being the main partition size), and then use `partclone` to clone the filesystem(s).

At first glance, the source disk looks pretty simple:

```
lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,FSTYPE,LABEL /dev/xvdf
NAME    SIZE TYPE FSTYPE LABEL
xvdf     60G disk        
└─xvdf1  60G part xfs    /
```

However, `parted` shows this "bios_grub" partition which, although sits first, is numbered 128:

```
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvdf: 125829120s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End         Size        File system  Name                 Flags
128     2048s  4095s       2048s                    BIOS Boot Partition  bios_grub
 1      4096s  125829086s  125824991s  xfs          Linux
```

1. Why is `lsblk` not showing the the "bios_grub" partition?
2. Why is it numbered 128 despite sitting first?
3. How to recreate/clone it on a new disk?

Comment: As XFS isn't offering (for the past 20+ years and still currently. There's hope for the future: https://lwn.net/Articles/877598/) a facility to be shrunk your plan will depend on partclone.xfs' actual support for shrinking the filesystem within the partition. I wouldn't count on your method staying as simple as you exposed it without working at the filesystem level (xfsdump, tar...)

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the heads-up, but I guess just recreating filesystem from scratch, cloning the UUID and rsyncing should cut it, no? Of course this will be done on a machine _not_ actually running on the filesystem.

Comment: You'd have to ask whoever came up with that for the AWS installer (?), but in general, partition numbering does not matter. Partition numbering can be in any order, if it bothers you, you can change it with `gdisk` or any other tool of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Probably because it only holds the core image of the `i386-pc` version of GRUB and not a recognizable filesystem, `lsblk` counts it as an "empty device". Try `lsblk -a` to see all block devices, including empty ones.

2.) Because whatever created it decided to use the very last slot in the GPT partition table for it, instead of filling the slots in order. It's a slightly unusual choice, but it should have no effect... unless you use a more pedantic partition editor which might rearrange the partition entries to match their order on the disk; then you might have to adjust your `/etc/fstab` to match if you're using device names (instead of following the current best practice of using filesystem UUIDs).

3.) Create an empty partition of 1MiB size on a GPT-partitioned disk, set its type to `bios_grub`, and then run `grub-install` (or `grub2-install` depending on distribution) on that disk.

Whenever you are installing an `i386-pc` version of GRUB (i.e. the version used with legacy BIOS-style booting) on a GPT-partitioned disk, a `bios_grub` partition is required to contain the GRUB core image that on a MBR-partitioned disk would be embedded in the free space between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition. `grub-install` will automatically detect GPT partitioning

Comment: 1) `lsblk -a` does not see it either; 3) This method does not read the source partition. I want a simple byte-to-byte clone like `dd if=src of=dst` which ideally should not care what the contents are. The problem is _where_ the source block device is?

Answer (score 0):

1. This may be due to many reasons - primarily traceable to how `lsblk` works. Have a look at the contents of /dev/disk. Also run `partprobe -s` and look for 'gpt partitions ...' which should include 128 if the partition is set up correctly. If not, there may be an issue with the VM image.
2. The number is arbitrary, and usually reflects creation order or conventions used in some script rather than sequence. As such, it may be an artifact of the partition table being changed to gpt after having been mbr.
3. The bios_grub partition is best managed by your OS. For example, Ubuntu's subiquity autoinstaller with curtin will allow you to set this up. This makes sense since the partition contents may need to differ, while cloning would yield identical ones. Adding to this, XFS cannot be shrunk. Thus, my recommendation is to do a clean install designed for dual bios_grub partitions, and then copy over the relevant partitions or applications.